# Bind Property of Property to GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datasource

Hey,
I would like to show the title and the price of a movie in my Gridview. The title and price are properties from the class Movie and Movie is a property of the class CartItem.

Here is the Code of my gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvShoppingCart" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
<Columns>
     <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" />
     <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The DataSource of my gridview is `List<CartItem>`.

This are the classes

```
public class CartItem
{
    private Movie _movieInCart;
    private int _Count;

    public CartItem()
    { }

    public CartItem(Movie movie, int count)
    {
        _movieInCart = movie;
        _count= count;
    }


    public Film MovieInCart
    {
        get { return _movieInCart; }
        set { _movieInCart = value; }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return _count; }
        set { _count = value; }
    }

    public double getSubTotal()
    {
        return _movieInCart.Price * _count;
    }
}


public class Movie
{
     private string _title;
     private double _price;

     public string Title
     {
         get { return _title; }
         set { _title= value; }
     }

     public double Price
     {
         get { return _price; }
         set { _price= value; }
     }     

//More properties here 
}
```

Apparently the GridView shows only first level properties, but how do I show these second level properties.

Many thanks,
Vincent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have two options:

1. Add properties to CartItem for Title and Price which delegate to the movie object.
2. Switch to use `TemplateField` instead of `BoundField`.

**Option 1:**

```
public string Title
{
   return _movieInCart != null ? _movieInCart.Title : null;
}
```

**Option 2:** (see [reference](http://www.apterainc.com/Blog/Post/09-12-02/Declarative_Databinding_of_Nested_Object_Properties_to_GridView_Columns.aspx))

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label
      runat="server"
      Text='<%# Bind("MovieInCart.Title") %>'>
    </asp:Label>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```